# Convert column value to column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, list, dataframe

| col a |
| --- |
| [test1,test2,test3] |
| [test3,test4,test5'] |

Output:

| col a | a_test1 | a_test2 | a_test3 | a_test4 | a_test5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [test1,test2,test3] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| [test3,test4,test5'] | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Will you please send the output of `print(df.head(1).to_dict())`?

Answer (score 0):

If `col a` contains lists of strings, you can do:

```py
tmp = df.explode("col a").reset_index()
x = df.merge(
    pd.crosstab(tmp["index"], tmp["col a"]).add_prefix("a_"),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                   col a  a_test1  a_test2  a_test3  a_test4  a_test5
0  [test1, test2, test3]        1        1        1        0        0
1  [test3, test4, test5]        0        0        1        1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cells in `col a` are actually lists of strings, you can try something like this:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.concat([df[col].str.join(';').str.get_dummies(';').add_prefix(col.split('_')[1] + '_') for col in df.columns])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
                   col a  a_test1  a_test2  a_test3  a_test4  a_test5
0  [test1, test2, test3]        1        1        1        0        0
1  [test3, test4, test5]        0        0        1        1        1
```